# Default size of treeset/CopyOnWriteArrayList in java?

Tags: java, collections, treeset, copyonwritearraylist

- What is the default size of `TreeSet` and `CopyOnWriteArrayList`?
- What is the load factor of `TreeSet` and `CopyOnWriteArrayList`?
- What is the size growth rate of `TreeSet` and `CopyOnWriteArrayList`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can easily refer the source code for your answers.

Comment: @Prashant Thanks for reply, I cant see the default capacity any where in source code for them. Please correct me if i am wrong here. Could you please help me here ?

Comment: Because there is none. Each time an item is added `TreeSet` or `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, the size incerases by `1`.

Answer (score 1):

The 3 properties you're asking about don't really apply to `TreeSet` and `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, same as they don't apply to e.g. `LinkedList`.

But if you want answers, they are:
**Default size: 0

Load factor: 100%

Size growth rate: 1**

I.e. the default/initial size is 0, they are always 100% full, and they grow/shrink by 1 every time an element is added/removed.